# Twitter bootstrap buttons appearing on hover over the table row

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap table with a button group in the last cell of each row.

[image: button group in a table cell]

I want these buttons appear only when user hovers over the row. Also, when user hovers over the row (not over the button group itself) only icons should appear, and when he then hovers over the button group icons should be displayed like buttons.

[image]

Here is a fiddle with `html` layout I use http://jsfiddle.net/hDafj/

And this is what I tried to do already http://jsfiddle.net/hDafj/2

Comment: where's the code you tried?

Comment: Added a link to html layout.

Comment: that's just the markup, what did you try to do?

Comment: Here is what I tried to do http://jsfiddle.net/hDafj/2/ But it just shows and hides the buttons. And I want it to show icons only on row hover, and buttons on button group hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think that anyway you need some additional styles here. I've added `.btn-group-hover` class to make the buttons' borders, shadow and background white (this way they will always be the same size). All `.icon-white` icons also should be treated separately to avoid them appearing white on white background on row hover. Here is my suggested solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hDafj/3/ But the only issue here is that it looks good only on white `tr` background.

Comment: Looks good! Do you think it is possible to make it work the same way using css only?

Comment: I think that it is possible, but in case of using jQuery browser support is better.

Answer (score 11):

We can do this with just `CSS`

**CSS**

```
table.table tr td div.btn-group { display:none;}
table.table tr:hover td div.btn-group { display:inline-block;}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/hDafj/235/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not exactly what I wanted. I want it to show icons **only** on row hover, and buttons on button group hover. Please, see what I tried to do already jsfiddle.net/hDafj/2

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/hDafj/5/ which might help you get started (need to fix the alignment, which you can d on your own

use js to add class and css for the row hover

```
$(".btn-group a").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("btn");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("btn");
}

);
```

css

```
.btn-group {
    visibility:hidden;
}
table tr:hover .btn-group {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You got the idea. But buttons jump on hover. I like the solution given by Iurii.K.